# Find and replace a string with multiple string in a loop line by line

Tags: powershell

Original Data :

```
<tr><td>ABerglund@domain.com</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>AHill@domain.com</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>KBrowne@domain.com</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>LBonifaz@domain.com</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>RBready@domain.com</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Bnet@domain.com</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Fzone@domain.com</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>KBN@domain.com</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

In File `<tr>` need to be replace with below list in sequence loop line by line

```
<tr class="danger">
<tr class="warning">
<tr class="active">
<tr class="success">
```

Tried :

```
$str = Get-Content C:\Users\admin\Desktop\n\2.html

#odd
$f=0; $str.Split("`n") | % { if($f = !$f) { $_ } }

#even
$g=1; $str.Split("`n") | % { if($f = !$f) { $_ } }

$f -replace "<tr>", '<tr class="active">'
$g -replace "<tr>", '<tr class="success">'
```

Result not came as expected

Comment: `$f -replace "<tr>", '<tr class="active">'` - the variable `$f` is your odd/even counter, it has no text in it to replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have four rotational classes count lines and do a modulus division `%`
and use a switch command.

```
$file = Get-Content "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\n\2.html"

$cnt=0
ForEach ($line in $file){
    if ($line -match '^\<tr\>') {
        switch ($cnt) {
            0 {$line -replace '\<tr\>','<tr class="danger">'}
            1 {$line -replace '\<tr\>','<tr class="warning">'}
            2 {$line -replace '\<tr\>','<tr class="active">'}
            3 {$line -replace '\<tr\>','<tr class="success">'}
        }
        $cnt++
        $cnt%=4
    } else {
        $line
    }
}
```

Or put the classes in an array and insert by index:

```
$file = Get-Content "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\n\2.html"
$classes = ('danger','warning','active','success')
$cnt=0
ForEach ($line in $file){
    if ($line -match '^\<tr\>') {
        $line -replace '\<tr\>', ('<tr class="'+$($classes[$cnt])+'">')
        $cnt++
        $cnt%=4
    } else {
        $line
    }
}
```